Since axioms described using normal language, have this ever created problems?
People formalized mathematics using axioms. But axioms still need a natural language to describe them. Have inaccuracy of definitions, caused by using natural language in stating axioms, ever created any problems?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Axioms like e.g. the Peano axioms and ZFC axioms will often be described with natural language, but can be written fully formally, in the sense that a computer can check whether an application of the axiom in a formal proof is valid without human input.

you can not argue any math without a natural language. How to do an axiom of numbers, without using the word number. Or what is a point, without using "point" So I think this question is meaningless
